# Android MotionLayout Pause

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Is it possible to pause Motion layout transition and then resume this transition?(for example I show dialog fragment and I need to pause this motion scene and after dismissing dialog I want to resume transition)
I launch transition by code like as `MotionLayout.setTransitionToEnd()`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the current progress and set to that value... then when you are ready to resume, you can call the transitionToEnd() again and it will resume from that value... so for example

```
private void pauseAnimation() {
    float currentProgress = motionLayout.getProgress()
    motionLayout.setProgress(currentProgress())
}

private void resumeAnimation() {
    motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
}
```

That should do what you are looking to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I found the public method in MotionLayout class `setProgress(float)` and `setInterpolatedPreogress(float)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout.html#setProgress(float)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout.html#setInterpolatedProgress(float)
which allows to resume animation

Answer (score 0):

You can store the position of progress that you left before pausing the fragment like so:

```
private var outState: Bundle? = null
const val KEY_CURRENT_POSITION_LIST_CATEGORY = "KEY_CURRENT_POSITION_LIST_CATEGORY"
```

```
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        outState = Bundle()
        outState!!.putFloat(KEY_CURRENT_POSITION_LIST_CATEGORY, motion_layout.progress)
    }
```

And `onResume`, you can just set the progress of the animation in the `motion_layout`

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (outState != null) {
        motion_layout.progress=outState!!.getFloat(KEY_CURRENT_POSITION_LIST_CATEGORY)
        }
    }
```